# Hide blank cells google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to hide lines automatically, without deleting them?
I have a drop-down list in B1, following this cell, some cells appear in C2: D11.
Depending on the value of cell B1, some lines are empty and I would like to hide them for better legibility.
I attach the link to my [test file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1x1oycItwx_I_69lQT03CsCJKPIwdTPPoOqL0k6-wWCY/edit#gid=889818228).

Cordially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide C, D, and E. The filter the blanks with this in F2:

```
=filter(C2:D11;not(isblank(D2:D11)))
```

Comment: @william I added a sheet to your test spreadsheet with a different approach for you to try. I included an explanation on the sheet.